# Swipe Down Gesture Not Working with react-native-tab-view on react-native-navigation Modal - iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-navigation, react-native-tab-view

In my application, I am using `react-native-navigation` to handle screen navigation and modals. I have implemented a modal that contains tabs using `react-native-tab-view`. Normally, when a modal is open using `react-native-navigation`, users can swipe down on the modal to close it. This gesture works as expected on other parts of the modal. However, I've noticed that this swipe-down gesture to close the modal does not work when performed over the area where the `react-native-tab-view` is displayed.

**Environment**:

- react-native: 0.72.5
- react-native-tab-view: 3.5.2
- react-native-navigation: 7.37.0-hotfix.1

**What I've Tried:**

- Verified that the swipe-down gesture works on other parts of the modal or without the tabview from react-native-tab-view.
- Searched for any related issues in the respective libraries, GitHub issues and discussions.

Thank you in advance for any help or suggestions!